# Display member with biggest value member in ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Any idea if in combobox exist feature that make display member with biggest value member?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: What do you want to do ? Any example code and whats going wrong?

Comment: No, you need to write your own method to set it. Like after loading the values in combo you calculate the biggest value and then do this comboBox1.SelectedValue = yourselectedValue;

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show any effort or code example, you can follow a structure like this;

```
int biggest = comboBox1.Items[0];
for (int i = 1; i < comboBox1.Items.Length; i++)
{
    biggest = GetBigger(comboBox1.Items[i], biggest);
}

comboBox1.SelectedItem.Value = biggest;


static int GetBigger(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return b;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I presume you left out LINQ on purpose :) +1